# python wont pass while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
counter = 1 
while counter:
    print(counter) 
    counter=counter + 1 
    if counter==True:
        print("NOPE, False") 
    if counter == 0:
        print("NOPE, 0") 
    if counter==False:
        print("YES, True") 
    elif counter==(0 or False):
        print("YES")
```

### What am I doing wrong?
For what reason do I have repetition 111111 at the output?
I want it to alternately print the texts below depending on whether the number is zero or some other number?

Update:
Thanks for the help, I tried to create a program that will change
values (increase number) and print a message with a while-loop.
After your help and clarification, it is clear that without more conditions and redirects I will not be able to get different outputs / text, so the task itself is not well set at the beginning.
Now I look stupid to myself when I look at my idea and this attempt...

Comment: why are you checking INTs against BOOLs?

Answer (score 2):

Positive integers are evaluated as `True` and counter is always positive. Thus the while-loop will run infinetly.

I don't know what the goal of your code is, but usually when you work with counters a while-loop is of the form:

```
while counter <= max_iter:
```

This will execute the while-loop until the counter reaches the value of max_iter.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is because `counter` is a variable of type int, you need to convert it to a boolean type, like so:

```
counter = 1 
while counter:
    print(counter) 
    counter=counter + 1 
    if bool(counter) == True:
        print("NOPE, False") 
    if counter == 0:
        print("NOPE, 0") 
    if bool(counter) == False:
        print("YES, True") 
    elif bool(counter) == False or counter == 0:
        print("YES")
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case example you have written the value of counter will always be "Truthy". If you write `while counter:` the conditional will always be true unless you set the value of counter to be either specifically either 0 or False.